# MongoDB Trigger for Azure Functions

Tags: mongodb, azure, triggers, azure-functions, atlas

Azure Functions don’t have a trigger for MongoDB right out of the box. Is there some custom MongoDB trigger out there that will allow for me to take advantage of Change Streams in MongoDB? Ideally, I would like to find a MongoDB trigger equivalent to the “CosmosDB” trigger in Azure Functions that takes advantage of Change Feed. If that doesn’t exist, is there some other way that I can take advantage of MongoDB change stream with Azure Functions? We use Azure Functions extensively and need some way to incorporate it with MongoDB. Specifically, we need a trigger for database changes in MongoDB. I’ve seen examples of using Azure Functions with MongoDB with a Http Trigger, but we need a trigger that makes use of the MongoDB change stream.

Comment: this one https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/how-to-integrate-azure-functions-with-mongodb ?

Comment: I've seen that one.  Unfortunately, it's not what I'm looking for.  The tutorial uses an HTTP trigger in the Azure Function.  What I'm looking for is a MongoDB trigger that picks up database changes in MongoDB.

Comment: there's no such thing.